# StrAlloc not working after migrating to Delphi XE7

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-2007, delphi-xe7

I am working on an application which was recently upgraded from Delphi 2007 to XE7. There is one particular scenario where the conversion of TMemoryStream to PChar is failing. Here is the code:

```
procedure TCReport.CopyToClipboard;
var
  CTextStream: TMemoryStream;
  PValue: PChar;
begin
    CTextStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    //Assume that this code is saving a report column to CTextStream
    //Verified that the value in CTextStream is correct
    Self.SaveToTextStream(CTextStream);

    //The value stored in PValue below is corrupt
    PValue := StrAlloc(CTextStream.Size + 1);
    CTextStream.Read(PValue^, CTextStream.Size + 1);
    PValue[CTextStream.Size] := #0;

    { Copy text stream to clipboard }
    Clipboard.Clear;
    Clipboard.SetTextBuf(PValue);

    CTextStream.Free;

    StrDispose(PValue);
end;
```

Adding the code for SaveToTextStream:

```
procedure TCReport.SaveToTextStream(CTextStream: TStream);
var
  CBinaryMemoryStream: TMemoryStream;
  CWriter: TWriter;
begin

  CBinaryMemoryStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  CWriter := TWriter.Create(CBinaryMemoryStream, 24);

  try
    CWriter.Ancestor := nil;
    CWriter.WriteRootComponent(Self);
    CWriter.Free;

    CBinaryMemoryStream.Position := 0;

    { Convert Binary 'WriteComponent' stream to text}

    ObjectBinaryToText(CBinaryMemoryStream, CTextStream);
    CTextStream.Position := 0;
  finally
    CBinaryMemoryStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I observed that the StrLen(PChar) is also coming out to be half the size of TMemoryStream. But in Delphi 2007 it was coming out to be same as the size of TMemoryStream.

I know that the above code is assuming the size of a char to be 1 byte, and that could be a problem. But I tried multiple approaches, and nothing works.

Could you suggest a better way to go about this conversion?

Comment: In what encoding does `SaveToTextStream` store the data? The correct way of fixing your code depends on the encoding that gets used. Three realistic possibilities are 1) the same encoding as `UnicodeString` (UTF-16LE) 2) UTF-8 3) the same encoding as `AnsiString` (which depend on Windows active code page).

Comment: Why has this been voted down??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reffering to what [hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743382/hvd) and [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan) wrote above, one possible way is to change `CTextStream` on `CopyToClipboard` to `TStringStream` as follow :

```
procedure TCReport.CopyToClipboard;
var
  CTextStream: TStringStream;
begin
    CTextStream := TStringStream.Create;
    try
      //Assume no error with Self.SaveToTextStream
      Self.SaveToTextStream(CTextStream);

      { Copy text stream to clipboard }
      Clipboard.AsText := CTextStream.DataString;
    finally
      CTextStream.Free;
    end;
end;
```

But you should **make sure** that `SaveToTextStream` function provides `CTextStream` with the exact encoding text data.

Comment: This works! SaveToTextStream accepts TStream as input parameter. Just what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be rather poor advice to me. As written the code forces the use of ANSI. Surely that should be avoided. @jetty, are you really embracing the move to Unicode? How is `SaveToTextStream` implemented? Does `TCReport` contain a textual representation?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes you are right about forcing the use of ANSI. It would be better if `TCReport` has `ReportAsText` method as you said. I suggest this with a little warning at the end for not knowing how `SaveToTextStream` implemented with assumption it would be safe to be converted to ANSI.

Answer (score 8):

Yet again, this is the issue of Delphi 2009 and later using Unicode text. In Delphi 2007 and earlier:

- `Char` is an alias to `AnsiChar`.
- `PChar` is an alias to `PAnsiChar`.
- `string` is an alias to `AnsiString`.

In Delphi 2009 and later:

- `Char` is an alias to `WideChar`.
- `PChar` is an alias to `PWideChar`.
- `string` is an alias to `UnicodeString`.

Your code is written assuming that `PChar` is `PAnsiChar`. Hence your problems. You need to stop using `StrAlloc` anyway. You are making life hard for yourself by manually allocating heap memory here. Let the compiler do the work.

You need to obtain your text in a string variable, and then simply do:

```
Clipboard.AsText := MyStrVariable;
```

Exactly how best to obtain the string depends on the facilities that `TCReport` offers. I expect that it will yield a string directly in which case you'll write something like this:

```
procedure TCReport.CopyToClipboard;
begin
  Clipboard.AsText := Self.ReportAsText;
end;
```

I'm guessing as to what your functionality your `TCReport` offers, but I'm sure you know.

Comment: +1. This.  People who claim to be porting to unicode delphi without knowing what they are doing, will make a hash of everything they do. Manually allocating (with StrAlloc or GetMem) is a code-smell, unless it is necessary.  Leaving code in there that was stupid even in Delphi 7 era, is a sign of a barely-competent developer.

Comment: Hi @DavidHeffernan, could you take a look at the edited code? I have mentioned the code for SaveToTextStream.

Comment: What encoding does `ObjectBinaryToText` use?

Comment: I can see that the Text has been composed of WriteAsciiStr and WriteUTF8Str. Does this tell about the UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: I think you need to be clear on what the encoding is. Whatever it is you need to match that with your string stream. Anyway, I gave you yet high level answer that concentrated on the concepts. You accepted an answer that provided code without explanation as the the problem, and that was potentially misleading. In my opinion you should be trying to understand and learn rather than just pasting code of whose consequences you are not clear.

Comment: I have to admit that I don't really understand your reasoning here